# Optimizing query in MySQL- joins and subqueries?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, optimization, subquery

I have several tables: a table of users, and tables recording various actions they can take (i.e. downloading, reading, quiz, etc.). I am trying to produce a table listing each individual user, and the number of actions they have taken thus far.

```
SELECT a.user_id, b.action1 + c.action2 + d.action3 AS actions
FROM table_of_applicable_users a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT e.user_id , COUNT( e.user_id ) AS action1
    FROM table_of_actions1 e
    JOIN user_records f ON f.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE f.group_id =15
    GROUP BY e.user_id )b
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT g.user_id , COUNT( g.user_id ) AS action2
    FROM table_of_actions2 g
    JOIN user_records h ON h.user_id = g.user_id
    WHERE h.company_id =15
    GROUP BY g.user_id )c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT i.user_id , COUNT( i.user_id ) AS action3
    FROM table_of_actions3 i
    JOIN user_records j ON j.user_id = i.user_id
    WHERE j.company_id =15
    GROUP BY user_id )d
JOIN user_records z ON z.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE z.group_id =15
GROUP BY a.user_id
```

I join the user records table in each sub-query because I found it reduces the number of rows by approximately half. However, the query still takes far too much time. How might I further optimize this query, or create a new query that returns similar results?

p.s. The desired format for the results is as follows:

```
user_id    number of actions
00001      459
00002      2461, etc.
```

Comment: and you have this tables and queries in mysql and sql server?

Comment: that you can only say,that why you are using distinct.Beside there are also unnecessary join use.are you sure above query is running and giving correct output ? because on clause is missing after each left join .If t'row there is one more action,will you create one more table and so on.

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Unless you have a recent version of MySQL, `JOIN`ing multiple subqueries is very inefficient.  This is because the subqueries have no indexes.  5.6.7 added such.  What version are you running?  (That is, either an upgrade could help, or there is something else causing poor performance.)

Comment: This is on a MySQL server running version 5.6.16-log. I tried Rick James approach, and the time is shaved down to 44 seconds for the largest group, which is a great improvement over previously. I will try the other solutions soon and mark the best one. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: The UNION ALL method suggested by Kumar and improved by Rick proved most efficient. Thank you again. Rick, I checked for inflation as you said, and found no inconsistencies, though I will keep a close eye on future results just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KumarHarsh was close.  But a couple of fixes are needed:

```
Select user_id, SUM(actions) AS actions from  -- Note: SUM
(
( SELECT  e.user_id , COUNT(*) AS actions
    FROM table_of_actions1 e
    JOIN user_records f ON f.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE f.group_id = 15
    GROUP BY e.user_id )
UNION ALL
( SELECT  g.user_id , COUNT(*) AS actions
    FROM table_of_actions2 g
    JOIN user_records h ON h.user_id = g.user_id
    WHERE h.company_id = 15
    GROUP BY g.user_id )
UNION ALL
( SELECT  i.user_id ,  COUNT(*) AS actions
    FROM table_of_actions2 j
    JOIN user_records j ON j.user_id = i.user_id
    WHERE j.company_id = 15
    GROUP BY user_id )
) t4
)
GROUP BY user_id;   -- Note: GROUP BY
```

But!... Because of the `JOIN`, the `GROUP BY` may give an excessive value for the `COUNT`.  Recommend you check this to see if it gets the right count, or some inflated value:

```
SELECT e.user_id , COUNT(*) AS action1
    FROM table_of_actions1 e
    JOIN user_records f ON f.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE f.group_id = 15
    GROUP BY e.user_id;
```

If it is inflated, then we will have to work a lot harder to make your query both fast *and* correct.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your requirement,
Things that i remove from my query i found to be uneccessary .

```
Select user_id,action1+action2+action3 AS actions from
(
SELECT  e.user_id , COUNT( e.user_id ) AS action1
    FROM table_of_actions1 e
    JOIN user_records f ON f.user_id = e.user_id
    WHERE f.group_id =15
    GROUP BY e.user_id

union all

SELECT  g.user_id , COUNT( g.user_id ) AS action2
    FROM table_of_actions2 g
    JOIN user_records h ON h.user_id = g.user_id
    WHERE h.company_id =15
    GROUP BY g.user_id 

union all
SELECT  i.user_id , COUNT( i.user_id ) AS action3
    FROM table_of_actions3 i
    JOIN user_records j ON j.user_id = i.user_id
    WHERE j.company_id =15
    GROUP BY user_id
)t4
```

Answer (score 0):

Is userid column in table_of_actions1, table_of_actions2, table_of_actions3 and user_records is indexed ?. Try the following statement once

`SELECT a.user_id, b.action1 + c.action2 + d.action3 AS actions
FROM table_of_applicable_users a
LEFT JOIN 
   (SELECT DISTINCT e.user_id , COUNT( e.user_id ) AS action1
     FROM table_of_actions1 e
       JOIN (SELECT user_id, group_id from user_records where group_id = 15) f ON f.user_id = e.user_id
     WHERE f.group_id =15
     GROUP BY e.user_id )b
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT g.user_id , COUNT( g.user_id ) AS action2
     FROM table_of_actions2 g
     JOIN (SELECT user_id, company_id from user_records where company_id= 15) h ON h.user_id = g.user_id
     WHERE h.company_id =15
     GROUP BY g.user_id )c
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT i.user_id , COUNT( i.user_id ) AS action3
     FROM table_of_actions3 i
     JOIN (SELECT user_id, company_id from user_records where company_id = 15) j ON j.user_id = i.user_id
     WHERE j.company_id =15
     GROUP BY user_id )d
JOIN user_records z ON z.user_id = a.user_id
WHERE z.group_id =15
GROUP BY a.user_id`